# I am getting this error of "SenderType' cannot be constructed because it has no accessible initializers" while using the MessageKit in swift

Tags: ios, swift, messagekit

I am using the latest version of the MessageKit for the practice, and I am getting this error of "'SenderType' cannot be constructed because it has no accessible initializers" during compilation,

why it happened and please recommend the solution as well

thank you

```
    import Foundation
    import UIKit
    import MessageKit

    struct Member {
        let name: String
        let color: UIColor
    }

    struct Message {
        let member: Member
        let text: String
        let messageId: String
    }

    extension Message: MessageType {
**//ERROR IS SHOWN HERE**
        var sender: SenderType {
            return SenderType(id: member.name, displayName: member.name)

        }

      /*  var sender: Sender {
            return Sender(id: member.name, displayName: member.name)
        }*/

        var sentDate: Date {
            return Date()
        }

        var kind: MessageKind {
            return .text(text)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well Protocol is just a blueprint, not a fully fledged Type (sometimes called as Existential Type).

But, whoever adopts & conforms to it is actually a Concrete Type and that Class/Struct/Enum can/should be instantiated.

Reference: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Protocols.html

Answer (score 0):

`SenderType` is a `PROTOCOL`. You will see that when you `CMD+Control^+Click` on that `SenderType`. So what would you do about it? Xcode says it has no constructor, indeed it has no constructor (`init()`) as you can see in its description.

`MessageType` is a `PROTOCOL` too. And what you did is implement its functions/variables. So do the same with `SenderType`. Implement its functions/variables:

1. **senderId**
2. **displayName**

Finally, you would have like this:

```
extension Message: MessageType, SenderType {
    var senderId: String {
        return member.name
    }

    var displayName: String {
        return member.name
    }

    var sentDate: Date {
        return Date()
    }

    var kind: MessageKind {
        return .text(text)
    }
}
```